# How to search for an exact word/phrase using Sitecore Advanced Database Crawler?

Tags: sitecore, lucene.net, sitecore6

Can the Sitecore Advanced Database Crawler be used to search for an exact word/phrase (not a sub-string). I have tried using a wildcard search but failed. I have googled for this, but can't find any suggestions or solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the Sitecore.Search API will rewrite your query to utilize a `Lucene.Net.Search.PrefixQuery`, which won't give you the exact phrase match that you're looking for. There is an overload on `Sitecore.Search.IndexSearchContext` which accepts a `Sitecore.Search.PreparedQuery`, which bypasses much of this rewrite logic and ultimately results in use of a `Lucene.Net.Search.TermQuery` instead, giving you an exact phrase match.

Advanced Database Crawler (now referred to as Sitecore Search Contrib) does not utilize the PreparedQuery overload by default. You'll need to modify the `QueryRunner` to do this. An example can be seen [in this pull request](https://github.com/sitecorian/SitecoreSearchContrib/pull/6). You can also pull down the [Active Commerce SitecoreSearchContrib fork](https://github.com/ActiveCommerce/SitecoreSearchContrib), which includes this enhancement.

Comment: Hi, Techphoria414, thanks for you solution. It works. I wonder is it possible for me to search for any item that doesn't contain particular keyword?

Comment: Please post a new question and I can help answer that there. :)

Comment: @techphoria: I was also wondering if there is any online resources besides Brian and Alex posts regarding ADB Crawler if you know?

Comment: Hey gentlemen. I'm happy to help with your questions, but per the Stackoverflow format, please post them as new questions.